# Can not add options in aria2 using Python xmlrpc?

Tags: python, json, linux, download, xml-rpc

I am using aria2 as a download client for remote control.

As what aria2 shows, it supports `--on-download-complete`, it can pass 3 parameters to the executed script. Here's is the reference: https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html?highlight=on-download#event-hook

But now I am using a Python xmlrpc wrapper to talk to Aria2. this is the wrapper i am using: https://github.com/alfateam123/pyaria2

`server = PyAria2(
    'localhost',
    6800,
    rpcSecret={"useSecret": False, "secret": None}
)
unique_id_accepted = server.addUri([http://somewhere.com/somefile.iso],
                                  options={
                                      "dir": "/srv/",
                                      "gid": "abcdef1234567890",
                                      "max-connection per-server": 5,
                                      "on-download-complete": "touch /tmp/done"
                                  }
                                  )`

if Aria2 starts to download from the URI, the `unique_id_accepted` is the same as `gid` in this scenario. Actually aria2 works. When I see the downloading jobs in Aria2, the `gid` is accepted. But after it completes, it does not execute the command `touch /tmp/done`

Is there something wrong with the options?

How could you talk to aria2 to execute commands after it completes?

So many thanks!

---

update I found `Sample XML-RPC Client Code`
https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#sample-xml-rpc-client-code

I tried this line: `"onDownloadComplete": "touch /tmp/done"` but it still does not work.

---

updated

version of aria2c `aria2c -v`

`1.18.1
** Configuration **
Enabled Features: Async DNS, BitTorrent, Firefox3 Cookie, GZip, HTTPS, Message Digest, Metalink, XML-RPC
Hash Algorithms: sha-1, sha-224, sha-256, sha-384, sha-512, md5
Libraries: zlib/1.2.8 libxml2/2.9.1 sqlite3/3.8.1 GnuTLS/2.12.23 libgcrypt/1.5.3 c-ares/1.10.0`

Comment: You can refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64898215/any-example-of-aria2-notifications-listening-like-ondownloadcomplete-ondownload/69587231#69587231

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

It only supports "event hook" in command line.

Here is the solution: https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#event-hook

We should add the executed script in this format.

The experiment I did before was not suitable to Aria2c. It was born with this defect (Proved).

Hope this could be helpful for another soul :P